# How to query complex n:m relationship for getting an IEnumerable in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

In my sql database I have a many to many (n:m) relationship as given below:
[image: table relationship]

For my asp.net web application (with EF and database first approach) I need to extract all records (with C# and linq) of the table Quality for all groups that are members in the same association**s** that a given group is member of.

Below I have given sample data to demonstrate the needed query result for a given group with G_Id = 1

[image: sample data]

From the sample data we see that the given group is a member of association A_Id = 1 and A_Id = 2. So we need to look which other groups are members of these associations. In the given data we see, that the group with G_Id = 2 is also a member of association A_Id = 1 and the group with G_Id = 3 is also a member of A_Id = 2.
Thus we have to collect all records from the table Quality where G_Id = 1, G_Id = 2 and G_Id = 3 and the query result is:

[image: Query result]

I was able to write a working C# IEnumerable controller action (see below) for getting all *Quality* records for one group but failed to come up with a query that also accounts for the records of the associated groups.

```
public IEnumerable<Quality> Get()
{
    int g_Id = myAppPrincipal.G_Id;
    var group = UnitOfWork.GetById<Group>(g_Id);
    var groupQualities = group.Qualities;
    // Qualities is a public virtual ICollection of Quality inside the class Group

    IList<Quality> result = groupQualities.Select(entity => new Quality()
    {
        Q_Id = entity.Q_Id,
        Description = entity.Description,
        ...
    }).ToList();

    return result;
}
```

If someone could help me with building the correct query I'd be grateful.

See below class structure:

```
public class Entity
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Unique identifier
    /// </summary>
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public virtual int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Concurrency check property
    /// </summary>
    [Timestamp]
    public virtual byte[] Version
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether entity is new
    /// </summary>
    [Bindable(false)]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public virtual bool IsNew
    {
        get
        {
            return Id == 0;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.DumpToString();
    }
}

public class Association: Entity
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Assoc_Group: Entity
{
    public int A_ID { get; set; }
    public int G_ID { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public override byte[] Version
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class Group: Entity
{
    public Group()
    {
        Qualities = new List<Quality>();
    }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Quality> Qualities { get; set; }

}

public class Quality: Entity
{
    public int? G_ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public override byte[] Version
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

and corresponding mappings:

```
public class AssociationMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Association>
{
    public AssociationMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        HasKey(t => t.Id);

        // Properties
        Property(t => t.Description)
            .IsRequired();

        // Table & Column Mappings
        ToTable("Association");
        Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("A_ID");
        Property(t => t.Description).HasColumnName("Description");

        Ignore(t => t.Version);
    }
}

class Assoc_GroupMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Assoc_Group>
{
    public Assoc_GroupMap()
    {

        ToTable("Assoc_Group");
        Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("AG_ID");
        Property(t => t.A_ID).HasColumnName("A_ID");
        Property(t => t.G_ID).HasColumnName("G_ID");

        Ignore(property => property.Version);
    }
}

public class GroupMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Group>
{
    public GroupMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        HasKey(t => t.Id);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        ToTable("Group");
        Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("G_ID");


        Ignore(t => t.Version);
    }
}


public class QualityMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Quality>
{
    public QualityMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        HasKey(t => t.Id);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        ToTable("Quality");
        Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Q_ID");
        Property(t => t.G_ID).HasColumnName("G_ID");
        ...

        // Relationships
        HasOptional(t => t.Group)
            .WithMany(t => t.Qualities)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.G_ID);
    }
}
```

Comment: are you using the code first approach or database first approach of EF?

Comment: I am using database first approach

Comment: Please add class structure to get us started to help you. :)

Comment: class stucture is as given in the given relationship scheme (Ids are int as primary key and all other fields are strings)

Comment: No we need a class structure. because we don't know about your navigation properties and other.

Comment: Ok, give me a few minutes

Comment: `to extract all records of the table Quality for all groups that are members in the same association that a given group is member of` I assume you mean **associations** (plural), since a group can belong to multiple associations? If not, how are you defining _which_ of a group's association you're focusing on in your query?

Comment: yes, associations (plural). Sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested queries like this:

```
DECLARE @GivenGroup AS Int = 1

SELECT DISTINCT Q_Id
FROM Quality q
WHERE q.G_Id IN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT G_Id
    FROM Assoc_Group ag
    WHERE ag.A_Id IN
    (
        SELECT a.A_Id
        FROM Association a
        INNER JOIN Assoc_Group ag ON a.A_Id = ag.A_Id
        WHERE ag.G_Id = @GivenGroup
    )
)
```

At least for SQL Server.

You can try it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6dcc6/2

To query your SQL Database with C# you can use the SqlClient

```
var SQL = new StringBuilder();
// Build SQL here. use SQL.AppendLine("SELECT ...")
var cn = new 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(your_sql_connection_string);
var da = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(SQL.ToString(), cn);
var datatbl = new DataTable();
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@GivenGroup", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1; // use parameterization always.
try {
    da.SelectCommand.Connection.Open();
    da.Fill(datatbl);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // error handling here
}
finally
{
    cn.Close();
    cn.Dispose();
    da.Dispose();
}
// read from datatable
foreach (DataRow row in datatbl.Rows)
{
    Console.WriteLine(row["G_Id"].ToString());
}
```

May contain errors.

Comment: I tried it out and it gave the correct result. However I'd prefer to do it in C#. If I can't get it to work with C# I will try it with mapping an sql view. Thanks in any case!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean you want to do it in C#? You query the database with an sql in any case, do you not?

Comment: @Manu I added c# code for querying databases. does this help?

Comment: yes you are correct that when I query with C# then behind the scene sql querries are executed.

Comment: And all the code for establishing the connection to the sql db is setup in my DataAccess part of  EF and I am used to access the db tables via C# using linq.

Comment: @Manu I'm afraid I am no good with linq. You should probably be more specific with your question in that case and add some tags.

Comment: Your help was very valuable! Thank you again.  And yes, a tag to linq-to-sql was definitely missing. I just added it.

Answer (score 1):

As far I understand, you need all the group qualities that fall in all the parent  associations of some specific group, so:

```
public IEnumerable<Quality> Get()
{
    int g_Id = myAppPrincipal.G_Id;
    var group = UnitOfWork.GetById<Group>(g_Id);
    var associatedGroups = group.Assoc_Group.Groups;
    var qualities = new List<Quality>();
    foreach (var assoc in associatedGroups.Select(t => t.Association).Distinct())
    {
        qualities.AddRange(assoc.Assoc_Groups.SelectMany(t => t.group.Qualities).ToList());
    }

    var result = qualities.Distinct();
    return result;
}
```

In the above case, I am expecting **GetById** getting the associated entities also, if no, then you have to change to **GetById** method to include associated entities. Otherwise, you can get the associated separately by making separate calls.